# Docker.Dotnet :: Trying to enlist all the nodes in a Swarm

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I've been trying to enlist all nodes in my docker swarm but it throws a weird type conversion error.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

1. Connected to Docker using DockerClient object (using Docker.DotNet NuGet package)
2. Made a separate thread to get the response from the Async Function (LoadNodesAsync).
3. Tried to traverse through the response using an enumerator.

**Here's the complete code:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args){
    while (true)
    {
        GetNodesList();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}

async static private void GetNodesList(){
    try
    {
        DockerClient Client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
            new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"))
            .CreateClient();

        CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var result = await Client.Swarm.ListNodesAsync(cancelSource.Token);
        var enumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.ID.ToString());

        cancelSource.Cancel();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

It throws an exception inside **GetNodesList** function where the following line is written:

```cs
var result = await Client.Swarm.ListNodesAsync(cancelSource.Token);
```

Exception:

> Error converting value "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[System.Byte]'. Path '[0].Description.TLSInfo.CertIssuerSubject', line 1, position 1608.

The result objects contain **Not Yet Computed**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Exception:

Error converting value "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Byte]'. Path '[0].Description.TLSInfo.CertIssuerSubject', line 1, position 1608.

Comment: That sounds like either a bug in the library or (I would assume this) changes to the response of docker that do not match with the library version. I never used swarm but I do know for k8s client library version must match with cluster version. Therefore you could check compatibility

Comment: As a quote from Docker.DotNet's github repo: `Version of this package uses SemVer format: MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH. MINOR segment indicates the Docker Remote API version support. For instance v2.124.0 of this library supports Docker Remote API v1.24. This does not guarantee backwards compatibility as Docker Remote API does not guarantee that either.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my approach was fine. The issue was caused by a **bug in Docker.DotNet library's version 3.125.4**.
The issue can be **resolved by using the previous version of the library**, ie: **version 3.125.2.**